# Detecting the genus of a surface by walking straight ahead

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I have a - maybe misled - intuition that one could "somehow" detect that one lives on a torus (of genus 1) just by walking around straight ahead and making appropriate observations.

Living on a "true" sphere, such a observation might be: [all geodesics are closed and simple](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28622/surfaces-all-of-whose-geodesics-are-both-closed-and-simple). There are [deformations of the sphere where this still holds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28622/surfaces-all-of-whose-geodesics-are-both-closed-and-simple/28627#28627) - but supposedly no other surfaces. So, if I observe that *in whatever direction - and from whereever - I start walking straight ahead, I return to the starting point*, I can conclude that I live on a (topological) sphere (of genus 0).

> Are there comparable observations I can make while walking around straight ahead
>   to conclude that I live on a (topological) torus?

Comment: In every orientable surface of non-positive constant curvature  there are geodesics which have no self-intersections (I think!). If you happen to pick one of them to walk on you will get no information to distinguish them.

Comment: On the other hand, in a surface of constant negative curvature $-k$ most geodesic segments of length $l$ have about $k/2\pi^2(g-1)$ self intersections, with $g$ the genus. This means that if you are able to see see self-intersections of your path you can estimate the genus. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2060.pdf (By the way, to  make sense of your «walking straight ahead» one needs the surface to be given a Riemannian metric or something good enough to define geodesics or something: a topology will no do, probably)

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to my MO question, [Probing a manifold with geodesics](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81622/probing-a-manifold-with-geodesics).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've definitely been interested. Do you know more concerning fedja's interesting comment, in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to Joseph's question [Probing a manifold with geodesics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81622/probing-a-manifold-with-geodesics) MO-ist `fedja` writes:

> [...] if two closed curves on the manifold have just one intersection and it
>   is transversal, that certainly should ring some bells [...]

If one can prove that two such closed curves cannot be homotopic one knows at least that the fundamental group of the manifold is not trivial.

(The question remains: Can this be proved - and how?)